# How to fix my app to login using id and password online using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm a beginner in Android Studio. By watching a video I made this app to login to my application by using id and password stored in Firebase. Everything in my view is OK but when I run the app and enter id and password (even right one), it will crash.

I checked everything but still have problem. I took a picture of Logcat and upload here.

This is mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtUsername, edtPassword;
    Button btnSignIn;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtUsername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
        edtPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        btnSignIn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Students");

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                logIn(edtUsername.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void logIn(final String id, final String password) {

        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.child(id).exists()){

                    if (!id.isEmpty()){
                        User user=dataSnapshot.child(id).getValue(User.class);
                        if (user.getPassword().equals(password)){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User is Not Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User is Not Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is User.class page:

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String password;

    public String getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {

        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {
    }
}
```

and this is log result:

[image: Logcat result]

Comment: Your log cat is text output, so please provide it as a text. Text should not be trapped in images, as it is not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search-engine scrapers. Would you kindly edit this question to rectify this please? I will downvote now and will happily un-downvote once this is fixed. Code formatting on the stack trace is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You User.class defines **password** as **String** whereas in the firebase it is stored as **Long**.

```
User user=dataSnapshot.child(id).getValue(User.class);
```

## SOLUTION

Simply change your User.class file to:

```
public class User {

  private String id;
  private Long password;

  public String getId() {
    return "" + id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password.toString();
  }

  public void setPassword(Long password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public User() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Karan and thanks a lot for your response. it's really appreciated, but I still have the problem with the same error: **com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long**

Comment: Can you tell me what line is #49

Comment: User user=dataSnapshot.child(id).getValue(User.class);

Comment: i suppose you are saving password as a string right?

Comment: yes sir. it is saved before on Firebase. I just send the password to be compared with the one stored there

Comment: Yes, in Firebase Database NoSQL, change the type to Long.

Comment: If you feel that id in FirebaseDatabase serves only as a UUID, then converting it into a Long would do no harm as you will only loose the number characteristic,

Comment: can you help me more?

Comment: I mean how to change the type of "id" to long?

Comment: Didn't you create an entity on Firebase Database console for User?

Comment: sorry. I sent it to your twitter